# Can I enter a non-target foreign home in Chinese Checkers?

Tags: chinese-checkers

Given a game of Chinese Checkers
And that I have a marble next to a foreign home which is not the taget opposite

Can I place my marble in that foreign home?

Can I jump in and out of that foreign home if it takes me back outside?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of the rules. Some versions let the unused homes occupied by unused pegs making them unusable. But some versions let them open so they can be used.

This also implies that you can uses unoccupied foreign homes of other players.

[Source](http://www.mastersgames.com/rules/chinese-checkers-rules.htm).